# How to pass a function parameter to the generic structure in swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, generics

I am trying to pass a model/struct as a parameter in function and passing it to another struct/model with generic type  here is my code

---> Function

```
func getAPICallModelDecodable<T:Codable> (url:String,model:T,
                                          success: @escaping (_ responseObject:T?)->Void,
                                          failure: @escaping (_ error:String) -> Void ,
                                          method:HTTPMethod = .get) {
    print(type(of: model))
    AF.request(url,method:method).responseDecodable(of: FetchAPI<T(Want to pass model parameter here)>.self) { respons in
        print(respons)
        switch respons.result {
        case .success(let data):
            if data.flag! {
                success(data.data)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            failure(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

---> FetchAPI Struct

```
struct FetchAPI<T:Codable>:Codable {
    
    var flag: Bool?
    var statusCode: Int?
    var message: String?
    var data: T?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case flag = "Flag"
        case statusCode = "StatusCode"
        case message = "Message"
        case data = "Data"
    }
}
```

**Model parameter can be any codable structure**

Comment: FetchAPI<T.self>.self shows error "'>' is not a postfix unary operator"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently your function `getAPICallModelDecodable` is defined in such a way that you have to pass in a model of type T. But if I understand it correctly, you only want to pass in (define) the type T.

For this you have to change the function as follows:

```swift
func getAPICallModelDecodable<T:Codable> (url: String, type: T.Type,
                                          success: @escaping (_ responseObject:T?)->Void,
                                          failure: @escaping (_ error:String) -> Void ,
                                          method:HTTPMethod = .get)
```

In the function body you can use T e.g. simply like this:

```swift
AF.request(url,method:method).responseDecodable(of: FetchAPI<T>.self)
```

The function call would then look like this:

```swift
getAPICallModelDecodable(url: ..., type: Model.self, ...)
```

Comment: failure occurs shows error ````Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead````

Comment: ````  MyApiManager.shared.getAPICallModelDecodable(url: ServerAPI.getProjects, model: [Projects].self, success: { response in
            success(response)
        }, failure: { error in
            failure(error)
        }) ````

Comment: @NoorAhmedNatali This error is a decoding error: your expected Model cannot be created from the given data. You have to adjust your type T, aka Model. Otherwise, Johannes' answer is completely correct. ;) Also a tip: try using a URLSession.shared directly instead AF (temporarily) in order to see clearly what's happening on the HTTP level.